# What is the "!" at the if statement

Tags: java

Can please someone explain me what the "!" after the if is ?

```
if (!(i > 0 && i < (str.length()-1) && str.charAt(i) == 'x')) {
```

Can I write the same without the "!" ?

Comment: Smells like a demorgan's exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!true` is `false` and `!false` is `true`.It's a `negation` operator.